# Windows Phone 7 memory management

Tags: performance, image, windows-phone-7, memory

I'd like to know if there are any specific strategies for handling memory, especially with respect to image caching on the Windows Phone. I have a very graphics intensive silverlight App which needs to keep it graphics that it retrieves from the internet and it needs to be able to freely roam about - but the memory requirement becomes quite huge after using the app for a couple of minutes.

I have tried setting the image's UriSource to null but I need to maintain the image backgrounds when I come back to the page. I'm at a loss because there isn't much information on the internet. The inbuilt profiling showed me "Texture Memory Dominant" and asked me to Analyze Heap Memory to resolve the issue, but I'm still clueless about these.

Any pointers to move forward?

Comment: It's all over the app - not anything in particular. I was just interested if someone has a strategy to deal with the high memory usage

Comment: For completely arbitrary problems? My solution is usually to fix the bloody problems in the code.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out. sine this is a model design issue and not a code problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will be general - similarly to your question. I presume that you know for sure that the problem is in images. (Because a simple ListBox with a few hundred text items can cost you many MB.)

If you search the web you'll find plenty of links such as [this one](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2011/01/17/images-and-memory-leaks-in-windows-phone-7/). But a general analysis is easy to do.

Take an image of the WP7 screen size, i.e. 480x800. 32-bit bitmap (I suppose this is what WP7 uses when the image is opened) takes roughly 1.5 MB (a simple multiplication).

The same jpg file can have 10x smaller size (for high quality compression) or even less.

Now what's done behind the scenes when you use the construction

```
<image source="http://..."/>.
```

(In the absence of any information from you, this is what I suppose you use.)

WP7 downloads the image and adds it to the cache. The cache apparently traces the use of the Uri pointing to the image.

As next the image gets opened, i.e. converted to a bitmap of native image size. Image gets downsampled in this process if it would exceed max. WP7 texture size.

You can customize the bitmap size as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx). If you care of quality, then you should use downscale factor 2, 4, or 8. In case of jpeg these factors represent by far the fastest option. (Well, I have no idea if you know the image resolution before the image gets loaded into the Image control. It is not too difficult to get this info from a jpg file, but right now I have no idea how it can be easily done on WP7.)

The bitmap gets freed if (my speculation) if the control's source is set to null. The downloaded image is purged from the cache when Uri is set to null. (This is reported on the web plenty times.)

If you take all this info, it should be possible to (kind of) control your use of the image cache. You can roughly estimate the image size and can decide which images remain in the cache. Maybe it will need some tricks such as storing Uri objects in you own structures and releasing them as needed. I am not saying this is easy to do, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Kinda makes sense, I was just putting it out there to see if there is a general strategy I wasn't aware of. thanks.

Comment: If I purged the images between page movements, how would I reload them on the event of the Back Key?

Comment: Image control will reload them.

Comment: if I null out the UriSource, they dont come back when you navigate between pages

Comment: I also noticed that if you tombstone the app, the memory footprint drops by half. it must be clearing something.

Comment: @if I null out the UriSource: BitmapImage.UriSource? How could you expect the control to display anything if you tell him to show nothing?

Comment: UriSource = null shows the image in the control but garbage collects the cache. when you return to that page there'll be nothing.